# Excel VBA array of Selected Range

Tags: vba, excel

I know how to make two functions on each column (in this case TRIM and STRCONV to ProperCase

```
Dim arrData() As Variant
Dim arrReturnData() As Variant
Dim rng As Excel.Range
Dim lRows As Long
Dim lCols As Long
Dim i As Long, j As Long

Range("H2", Range("H2").End(xlDown)).Select           
lRows = Selection.Rows.Count
lCols = Selection.Columns.Count

ReDim arrData(1 To lRows, 1 To lCols)
ReDim arrReturnData(1 To lRows, 1 To lCols)

Set rng = Selection
arrData = rng.Value

For j = 1 To lCols
    For i = 1 To lRow
        arrReturnData(i, j) = StrConv(Trim(arrData(i, j)), vbProperCase)
    Next i
Next j

rng.Value = arrReturnData
Set rng = Nothing
```

Currently I'm trying to figure out how to add one more FOR which where I could gather more than one selection ranges for example:

```
Set myAnotherArray(0) = Range("H2", Range("H2").End(xlDown)).Select
Set myAnotherArray(1) = Range("J2", Range("J2").End(xlDown)).Select
For k = 1 To myAnotherArray.lenght
```

Because I'm copying and pasting whole script to make aciton on three columns. Tried already:

```
Dim Rng As Range
Dim Area As Range

Set Rng = Range("Range("H2", Range("H2").End(xlDown)).Select,Range("J2", Range("J2").End(xlDown)).Select")
For Each Area In Rng.Areas
    Area.Font.Bold = True
Next Area
```

Even tried to Union range but I failed. Any sugesstions?

And as always... Thank you for your time!

Comment: Do the columns have the same number of rows? Hint - you also don't need to select the columns.

Comment: Can you use 1 Range which is a `Union` of these 2 Ranges ?

Comment: Do you have multiple worksheets? On your second bit of code on the For statement, `.lenght` would throw an error (length). On the third bit of code where you `Set Rng = ...`, you've turned your ranges into a string. Remove the quote marks around the inner `Range()`.

Comment: @ShaiRado I cannot becouse after union there are some werid things happening around.

To Tyeler: removing didn't help

Answer (score 0):

I found a way you could use to perform work on those ranges, refer to the code below:

```
Sub DoSomethingWithRanges()

Dim m_Worksheet      As Excel.Worksheet
Dim m_Columns()      As Variant

Set m_Worksheet = ActiveSheet

' fill all your columns in here
m_Columns = Array(2, 3, 4)

For Each m_Column In m_Columns

   ' the area being used ranges from the second until the last row of your column
   With m_Worksheet.Range(m_Worksheet.Cells(2, m_Column), m_Worksheet.Cells(m_Worksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count, m_Column))
      ' do things with range
      .Font.Bold = True
   End With
Next m_Column

End Sub
```

In the variant array `m_Columns` you can add all the columns you want. Only downside is that in my example you have to use numbers to specify columns instead of "H". However, you don't have to worry about the row-indexes, since the area automatically ranges from the second to the last used row.